# How to retrieve entries from a space in Contentful in Android

Tags: android, contentful

Just started using this service today and the documentation is a little bit confusing.
I have created a `Space` using the photo-gallery template. In this Space, I have entries of type Image, Author, and Photo Gallery. My Question is, how do I get retrieve an Image for example for display in my android app?

To Interact with the `Contentful Delivery API`, I know I have to use a `CDAClient` object and `CDAEntry` object for the entry am trying to get.

I have defined this in the `onCreate()` method of my `Fragment` class like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getActivity();

    client = CDAClient.builder()
            .setSpace("id-of-the-space-am-accessing")
            .setToken("the-access-token")
            .build();

    entry = client.fetch(CDAEntry.class).one("the id of the image I want to retrieve");
}
```

In the `onCreateView()` method, am trying to view the result like this:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Result: " + entry.toString());
```

When I run the app, I get this in Logcat:

```
E/NEWS ACTIVITY﹕ Result: CDAEntry{id='2YhtjbebgscIwO2keYEa4O'}
```

This id matches the id of the image I passed to `client.fetch(CDAEntry.class).one()`

Obviously am getting the image, but how do I display it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the [official documentation](http://docs.contentfulcda.apiary.io):

### Content Type

> Content Types are schemes describing the shape of Entries. They mainly consist of a list of fields acting as a blueprint for Entries.

### Asset

> Assets represent files in a Space. An asset can be any kind of file: an image, a video, an audio file, a PDF or any other filetype. Assets are usually attached to Entries through Links.

### Entry

> Entries are the documents contained within a space. They might represent blog posts or events or anything else that you have defined a content type for.

### Space

> All content in Contentful belongs to a space. You can think of spaces like databases, you will generally have at least one space for a project, but may opt to use a separate space for e.g. testing.

As mentioned above, it is quite common to have an Entry which wraps an Asset in order to include some additional meta-data about it. For example, consider the `Image` type, which has the following set of fields:

- title - Short Text
- photo - Link to Asset
- imageCaption - Long Text
- imageCredits - Long Text

With the Java/Android SDK these properties are accessible via the `getField()` method of the entry:

```
CDAEntry imageEntry = client.fetch(CDAEntry.class).one("foo");
String title = imageEntry.getField("title");
CDAAsset photo = imageEntry.getField("photo");
String photoUrl = photo.url(); // URL of the linked photo
String imageCaption = imageEntry.getField("imageCaption");
String imageCredits = imageEntry.getField("imageCredits");
```

Note that the `getField()` method infers the return type to avoid explicit casting, so make sure to use the correct types when calling it.

It is worth to mention that the `one(String id)` method is synchronous and will perform IO on the calling thread, so you can either use `one(String id, CDACallback callback)` or if you're comfortable with RxJava there's also `client.observe()` which gives you an `Observable`.

One final note is that in some cases it could be considered wasteful to fetch resources from the network every time your activity/fragment is created, and it's better to persist resources to a local database and have it accessible in offline mode. For that you might want to check out [Vault](https://github.com/contentful/vault), which is an annotation processor that helps you persist data from Contentful over SQLite with minimum effort, it uses the Contentful Sync API to get delta updates from a given space and with that reduce battery and data consumption while also helping to provide better offline behavior.

JavaDoc for the Java/Android SDK is here: http://contentful.github.io/contentful.java/

There are also some open-source sample apps that showcase usage of Vault with the space templates, for the photo gallery template it is available here: https://github.com/contentful/gallery-app-android

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Tom for your answer.I'll read this better and try them when I get back to my computer.

Comment: HI @Tom, so how do I get the Id of an entry when performing `client.fetch(CDAEntry.class).one("id");` without looking it up in the info tab?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do.. The IDs of the entries are available through the user-interface. If you have multiple entries and you want to fetch all of them e.g. by specific type, you could do `client.fetch(CDAEntry.class).where("content_type", "content-type-id").all()` and get a `CDAArray` instance. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yeah.That's exactly what I want.These methods are not available anywhere I know.And I've looked.Thanks though